# Deploy web app to Azure but still showing Microsoft page instead

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I'm trying to deploy my web app to Microsoft Azure and everything goes fine in visual studio. But when it launches it shows:

> Hey, App Service developers!
>   Your app service is up and running.
>   Time to take the next step and deploy your code.

How can I show my web page instead of this page?

Here is the output I get in Visual Studio.

```
------ Publish started: Project: RCMania, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Transformed Web.config using C:\DDAC\Assignment\RCMania\RCMania\Web.Debug.config into C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\RCMania-1747672403\obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
Auto ConnectionString Transformed C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\RCMania-1747672403\obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config into C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\RCMania-1747672403\obj\Debug\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\RCMania-1747672403\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp.
Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://rcmania.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=rcmania ...
Adding ACLs for path (rcmania)
Adding ACLs for path (rcmania)
Updating file (rcmania\Web.config).
Adding ACLs for path (rcmania)
Adding ACLs for path (rcmania)
Publish Succeeded.
Web App was published successfully http://rcmania.azurewebsites.net/
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last time i had an issue like this is was because of the Default Documents. Make sure you default page is listed in here and is above `hostingstart.html`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp7ma.png]

Comment: That was it yeah. Thanks a lot

Comment: I am having this issue on a Linux App, thus no "Default documents" tab. Is there a way to change .htaccess file or something like it?

Comment: You might be using a custom application, you will have to check how to configure default page for application.

Comment: Note that this only appears for Windows Apps.  For Linux Apps, you'll need to FTP to the directory.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the app was failing to start up due to an unhandled exception thrown in my startup code.

However, the reason it was difficult to diagnose is it wasn't shown in the logs in the "log stream" section of the Azure portal. (this is using linux with ASP.NET core 3.1)

When I used the SSH console, went into the /home/LogFiles directory I could see log messages saying what had gone wrong.

Comment: FTP also works for viewing those files. SSH isn't working for me for some reason. I haven't gotten my pages showing yet, though.

Comment: Thanks for this tip about the log files being different via SSH. That was a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

I had this now with an MVC project, where the default path is "/Home", or "/Home/Index" (either resolves, based on the routing rules). As a result, I didn't have a default "page", but I did have a default "path" of "Home". Putting this in, and deleting the entry for hostingstart.html, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for my Java application by adding something to the azure-webapp-maven-
plugin configuration in my POM file.

```
<appSettings>
    <property>
        <name>JAVA_OPTS</name>
        <value>-Dserver.port=80 -Dsite.root=/usr/local/appservice/parkingpage/ROOT</value>
    </property>
</appSettings>
```

Note the `ROOT` at the end of 'parkingpage'. I can't image this is the way to go, but this is what I found in the applications logs in Kudu and it works.

Note: this was on a Linux OS. I tried something similar on a Windows OS without success. On Windows, the -Dsite.appbase command line argument is overridden by Azure.