# Django Web app is successfully deployed on Azure App Service Linux but can only see Azure Default Page

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service, gunicorn

I recently published my Django local git repo to the Azure App Service with Python 3.7 runtime. The deployment said it is successful and active but I only see Azure Default Page when I browse it.

I can't find any logs anywhere and it shows no signs of errors. 
How can I solve this ?

UPDATE: My Azure Configuration settings does not have option for setting the default page setting. The web app I am deploying is for Django and not for ASP

Thanks and regards,
Rachhek.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy web app to Azure but still showing Microsoft page instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56587820/deploy-web-app-to-azure-but-still-showing-microsoft-page-instead)

Comment: Sorry, it is not a duplicate. My situation is from Django ! @Hannel

Comment: different application, same issue.  Check default page setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question. I solved the problem by fixing the gunicorn bind settings. My guess is by default it pointed to wsgi in some other directory.

I added the following startup command to the general settings of the Web App Configuration

```
gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --chdir /home/site/wwwroot/appname appname.wsgi:application
```

[image]

Comment: I have a similar problem but mine is a django app and I can't find the wsgi file. I have tried all combinations of the path `/home/site/wwwroot` and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Ok.  I will answer the question here.  Check the deafult document section of the Web App.

Make sure you default page is listed in here and is above `hostingstart.html`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp7ma.png]

Comment: Sorry, There is no section for "Default Documents" in my App Service. I can only see Application Settings, General Settings and Path Mappings.