# How do i access the Default Document tab on my Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

i am currently trying to display my deployed node.js express app on my azure app service, but can't access the default documents tab in the configuration settings.

My current View:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH2ZW.png

The setting view should look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp7ma.png ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56587820/deploy-web-app-to-azure-but-still-showing-microsoft-page-instead))

Am i missing a authorization for my account or is there a expanded view setting?

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using App Service on Linux.

For Linux App Service, there is no Default documents tab.

Configuration under Linux App Service:

[image]

Configuration under Windows App Service:

[image]